# AWS API Gateway and static HTML: "Execution failed due to configuration error: statusCode should be an integer which defined in request template"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to serve a static content using AWS API Gateway.
When I attempt to invoke the URL, both from the test page and from `curl`, I get the error:

> "Execution failed due to configuration error: statusCode should be an integer which defined in request template".

This is my configuration on Terraform:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "raspberry_api" {
  name        = "raspberry_api"
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate" "raspberry_alexa_mirko_io" {
  domain_name       = "raspberry.alexa.mirko.io"
  validation_method = "DNS"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "raspberry_alexa_mirko_io_cert_validation" {
  name    = aws_acm_certificate.raspberry_alexa_mirko_io.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_name
  type    = aws_acm_certificate.raspberry_alexa_mirko_io.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_type
  zone_id = var.route53_zone_id
  records = [aws_acm_certificate.raspberry_alexa_mirko_io.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_value]
  ttl     = 60
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "raspberry_alexa_mirko_io" {
  zone_id = var.route53_zone_id
  name = aws_acm_certificate.raspberry_alexa_mirko_io.domain_name
  type = "A"
  alias {
    name = aws_api_gateway_domain_name.raspberry_alexa_mirko_io.cloudfront_domain_name
    zone_id = aws_api_gateway_domain_name.raspberry_alexa_mirko_io.cloudfront_zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = true
  }
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "raspberry_alexa_mirko_io" {
  certificate_arn         = aws_acm_certificate.raspberry_alexa_mirko_io.arn
  validation_record_fqdns = [aws_route53_record.raspberry_alexa_mirko_io_cert_validation.fqdn]
  provider = aws.useast1
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_domain_name" "raspberry_alexa_mirko_io" {
  certificate_arn = aws_acm_certificate_validation.raspberry_alexa_mirko_io.certificate_arn
  domain_name     = aws_acm_certificate.raspberry_alexa_mirko_io.domain_name
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_base_path_mapping" "raspberry_alexa_mirko_io_base_path_mapping" {
  api_id      = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.raspberry_api.id
  domain_name = aws_api_gateway_domain_name.raspberry_alexa_mirko_io.domain_name
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "home" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.raspberry_api.id
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.raspberry_api.root_resource_id
  path_part   = "login"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "login" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.raspberry_api.id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.home.id
  http_method   = "GET"
  authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "integration" {
  rest_api_id             = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.raspberry_api.id
  resource_id             = aws_api_gateway_resource.subscribe_raspberry.id
  http_method             = aws_api_gateway_method.subscribe.http_method
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri                     = aws_lambda_function.raspberry_lambda.invoke_arn
  # This was just a failed attempt. It did not fix anything
  request_templates = {
    "text/html" = "{\"statusCode\": 200}"
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "login_page" {
  rest_api_id          = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.raspberry_api.id
  resource_id          = aws_api_gateway_resource.home.id
  http_method          = aws_api_gateway_method.login.http_method
  type                 = "MOCK"
  timeout_milliseconds = 29000
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "response_200" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.raspberry_api.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.home.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.login.http_method
  status_code = "200"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "login_page" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.raspberry_api.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.home.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.login.http_method
  status_code = aws_api_gateway_method_response.response_200.status_code
  response_templates = {
    "text/html" = data.template_file.login_page.rendered
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "example" {
  depends_on = [
    aws_api_gateway_integration.login_page
  ]
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.raspberry_api.id
  stage_name  = "production"
}
```

I have followed the instructions as in [this blog](https://blog.it-playground.eu/display-html-page-using-only-api-gateway/), with no success.

Comment: A simple typo. You put `status_code = "200"`, which is a string.  The datatype required is a Number, which would be `status_code = 200`.  In hindsight, the error message tried to give you that hint ;-)

Comment: @SherylHohman thanks, I spent HOURS on that with no success. Really appreciated...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"200" (with quotes) is considered a string, not an integer

try `status_code = 200` (without quotes)

Comment: I did this and still got the error "Execution failed due to configuration error: statusCode should be an integer which defined in request template" :(

Answer (score 7):

Just to repost [the excellent answer of TheClassic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59924471/17242583) here, the format seems to be:

```
request_templates = {
  "application/json" = jsonencode(
    {
      statusCode = 200
    }
  )
}
```

I also had this same problem, but looks like this works.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error because my code looked like this beforehand - inspired by the terraform docs.

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "api_gateway" {
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.api_gateway.http_method
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.api_gateway.id
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_gateway.id
  type        = "MOCK"
}
```

After reading this thread it now works looking like this:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "api_gateway" {
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.api_gateway.http_method
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.api_gateway.id
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_gateway.id
  type        = "MOCK"
  request_templates = {
    "application/json" = jsonencode(
      {
        statusCode = 200
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As per Bernie comment, this status code needs to be explicitly provided in request_templates attribute in **aws_api_gateway_integration** terraform resource.

After adding it I finally got 200 for OPTIONS that are integrated via MOCK endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

For others who might see this, this error can also be caused by a need to verify that when you use Mock as your Integration type, you confirm that your RequestTemplates contain statusCode and the value of statusCode is equal to one of your IntegrationResponses/ResponseTemplates/StatusCode

Something like:

```
    requestTemplates: {
      "application/json": "{\"statusCode\": 200}"
    }
```